# 403 Forbidden request, invalid auth credential

Tags: rest-api, integration

I am trying to connect third party from Salesforce. I am using Hmac sha256 algorithm for authentication and getting 403 error: Forbidden request, invalid auth credential

my code is as below: can anyone please guide me how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
          XmlStreamWriter w = new XmlStreamWriter();
          w.writeStartDocument('utf-8','1.0');
          w.writeStartElement(null,'LoanApplication',null); 
          w.writeStartElement(null, 'LoanReference', null);
          w.writeCharacters('APP1235');
          w.writeEndElement();
          w.writeStartElement(null, 'BrokerConsultantName', null);
          w.writeCharacters('Test');
          w.writeEndElement();
          w.writeEndDocument();

        DateTime dateTimeNow = dateTime.now();
        String unixTime = ''+dateTimeNow.getTime()/1000;        
        String xmlOutput = w.getXmlString();
        String privKey = 'test123456789';
        String publicKey = 'test987654321';
        String responseBody;        

        Blob blobSign = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA256', Blob.valueOf(privKey + xmlOutput.length() + unixTime));
        String HMACKey = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blobSign);

        String endpoint='https://api-test.test.com/test/test/new/';

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        request.setHeader('API-KEY',publicKey);
        request.setHeader('API-HMAC',HMACKey );
        request.setHeader('API-Timestamp',unixTime);
        request.setBody(XmlOutput);        


        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request); 
        responseBody = response.getBody(); 
        System.debug('@@@XML Output'+xmlOutput);     
        System.debug('@@@Response:'+ Response);
        System.debug('@@@Response Body:'+ ResponseBody);
        System.debug('@@@time: '+unixTime);
        System.debug('@@@HMACKey: '+ HMACKey);
        System.debug('@@@BlobSign: ' + blobsign);
```

Answer (score 2):

This line looks very suspicious:

```
Blob blobSign = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA256', Blob.valueOf(privKey + xmlOutput.length() + unixTime));
```

I'm guessing it should be something like:

```
Blob blobSign = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA256', Blob.valueOf(privKey + xmlOutput + unixTime));
```

Comment: Hi Metadaddy, Thank you for your reply. I tried removing the lenght, but the same 403 error.

Comment: One more observation - shouldn't you be using `Crypto. generateMac` if the API wants HMAC? So I'm guessing `Blob blobSign = crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(xmlOutput), Blob.valueOf(privKey));`

Comment: Hi Metadaddy, I tried with crypto.generateMac, but it is giving error - "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Crypto.generateMac(String, Blob)".

Comment: The Url is correct, but the issue still exists. working on it.

Comment: The `generateMac` method takes three arguments - algorithm, data and key

Comment: Hi Metadaddy, Finally got success message with right XML data format.

Comment: @SrikanthVivaram Which call you use to generate the digest? generateMac or generateDigest?

Comment: I used crypto.generateDigest